# Como limpar dados do formulário depois de salvar no banco de dados?via Ajax .net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

depois que salvo um objeto no banco, na view continua mostrando os campos preenchidos!

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Endereco:</legend>

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.CodigoPessoa, new { id = "Pessoa", name = "Pessoa" })
    @Html.Label("Cep: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.CEP, new { maxlength = "9", id = "Cep", name = "Cep", onchange = "findCEP()" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Endereco: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.DescricaoEndereco, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Endereco", name = "Endereco" })       
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Número: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Numero, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Numero", name = "Numero" })       
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Complemento: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Complemento, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Complemento", name = "Complemento" })      
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Bairro: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Bairro, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Bairro", name = "Bairro" })     

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Cidade: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Cidade, new { maxlength = "40", id = "Cidade", name = "Cidade" })   
    <br />
    @Html.Label("UF: ")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.UF, Model.UFList, new { id = "UF", name = "UF" })      
    <br />
```

```
function adicionarEndereco() {//Função Ajax  que obtem os valores dos campos e joga na action via post

    var codigoPessoa = document.getElementById("CodigoPessoa").value;
    var cep = document.getElementById("Cep").value;
    var endereco = document.getElementById("Endereco").value;
    var numero = document.getElementById("Numero").value;;
    var complemento = document.getElementById("Complemento").value;
    var bairro = document.getElementById("Bairro").value;
    var cidade = document.getElementById("Cidade").value;
    var temp = document.getElementById("UF");
    var uf = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Master/CadastrarEndereco",
            data: {
                CodigoPessoa: codigoPessoa,
                Cep: cep,
                DescricaoEndereco: endereco,
                Numero: numero,
                Complemento: complemento,
                Bairro: bairro,
                Cidade: cidade,
                UF: uf,


            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#endereco").html(data);
                //limpaForm();
            },


        });
}

   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult CadastrarEndereco(SuperViewModel enderecoVM)  //action que salva o objeto obtido na view e enviado via ajax
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enderecoVM.Bairro))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Bairro", "Bairro é obrigatório");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var endereco = Extentions.MapearEndereco(enderecoVM);
            EnderecoRepositorio.Cadastrar(endereco);
            EnderecoRepositorio.Commit();
        }
        var dados = new SuperViewModel();//crio outro objeto para a view soh com as minhas dropdownlist e os dados da minha grid
        dados.UFList = Extentions.ObterUF();
        dados.Enderecos = EnderecoRepositorio.ObterEnderecoPorPessoa(enderecoVM.CodigoPessoa);
        return PartialView("_EnderecoFields", dados);
    }
```

Comment: se eu retornar a PartialView sem o objeto vai quebrar !no objeto dados eu tenho uma dropdownlist que carrega na pagina e uma enumerable para uma grid que tbm uso na pagina!

Comment: pode montar um SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) no DotNetFiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Você já considerou usar *DataAnnotations* para dizer que o campo é obrigatório? Assim você não necessita usar esse **IF** em sua action.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a seguinte linha pra resetar o `form` automaticamente depois do retorno do `Ajax`:

```
$('#id_do_form').each (function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Master/CadastrarEndereco",
    data: {
        CodigoPessoa: codigoPessoa,
        Cep: cep,
        DescricaoEndereco: endereco,
        Numero: numero,
        Complemento: complemento,
        Bairro: bairro,
        Cidade: cidade,
        //UF: uf, Nessa linha não é necessário a utilização da ","
        UF: uf
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#endereco").html(data);
        $('#id_do_form').each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    },
});
```

### Exemplo:

```js
function iniciar(){
  document.getElementById("CodigoPessoa").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Cep").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Endereco").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Numero").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Complemento").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Bairro").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("Cidade").value = "teste";
  document.getElementById("UF").value = "teste";
}

function limpar(){
  $('#teste').each (function(){
    this.reset();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="teste" name="teste">
  <input type="text" id="CodigoPessoa"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Cep"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Endereco"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Numero"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Complemento"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Bairro"><br/>
  <input type="text" id="Cidade"><br/>
  <select id="UF">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="teste">teste</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
  
  <input type="button" onclick="iniciar()" value="Preencher">
  <input type="button" onclick="limpar()" value="Limpar">
</form>
```

---

### ** **EDIT** **

---

Eu costumo fazer isso em `PHP`, particularmente nunca mexi com `ASP` então não posso ajudar muito nesse caso.... mas irei mostrar como eu costumo fazer no `PHP`, quem sabe te elucide melhor de como proceder no `ASP`

### PHP

```
//Realizo as validações necessárias no lado do servidor antes de incluir ou excluir ou alterar....

function Incluir(){
    $con = new cmd_SQL(); //Abro conexão com o bd utilizando minhas conexões PHP

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"pt_BR"); //Seto a localização

    $db['tab']="tabela";
    $db['campos']="campos";
    $db['values']= $valores;

    if ($con->incluir($db)){ //Função criada em PDO para incluir
        echo "1"; //Se não houver nenhum erro na inclusão dos dados retorno 1
    }else{
        echo "0"; //Se houver erro na inclusão dos dados retorno 0
    }
}

function Excluir(){
    $con = new cmd_SQL();
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"pt_BR");

    $db['tab']="tabela";
    $db['cond']="campos=".$valores;

    if ($con->excluir($db)){ //Função criada em PDO para excluir
        echo "1"; //Se não houver nenhum erro na exclusão dos dados retorno 1
    }else{
        echo "0"; //Se houver erro na exclusão dos dados retorno 0
    }
}
```

No lado do cliente eu pego o retorno em `Ajax`, e trabalho com ele do seguinte modo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Master/CadastrarEndereco",
    data: {
        //dados
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#endereco").html(data);
        //data se refere ao meu retorno*, se foi incluído ou não com sucesso
        if (data == 1){
            //Foi incluido com sucesso, ou seja, devo usar a função Reset...
            $('#id_do_form').each (function(){
                this.reset();
            });
        }else{
            //Não foi incluido com sucesso, ou seja, não faço nada...
        }
    },
});
```

***[OBS*]** * O Retorno pode ser usado de `n` maneiras, eu costumo utilizar somente como 0 para falha ou 1 para sucesso na gravação...

Comment: Não seriamelhor um `document.getElementById("id_do_form").reset()`;

Comment: ele limpa os dados ate na hora de validar os campos! um campo obrigatório , ele limpa tudo e só fica a mensagem de erro("Campo obrigatório"). Já tentei assim, de uma forma deu certo ,mais na hora de validar nem tanto! os dados somem! preciso que os dados permaneçam nesta acao

Comment: Não entendi direito @HansMiller, o problema é o seu `validate`? Como assim os dados somem? Se puder explicar melhor o seu problema... @TobyMosque essa alternativa que você comentou é melhor Rs, sou um adepto ao NoJquery

Comment: O formulário também verifica e valida,veja bem o campo Bairro,ele é obrigatório não aceita nulo, se ele receber da view um valor nulo, ele retorna uma mensagem no topo do form informando que o campo é obrigatório, Se a gente implementar essa solução @Marcelo quando o usuário for cadastrar e esquecer o campo bairro, a função vai validar e mostrar a msgem. e depois  limpar o form não deixando informações para o usuário nos campos.para que ele saiba que esqueceu um campo e ele deve preencher.

Comment: Então você quer que a msg de erro continue aparecendo... você quer que limpe o formulário, mas as mensagens de erro apareçam correto?

Comment: seguinte utilizando essa função!@MarceloBonifazio e utilizando o form para cadastrar ,funciona de boa! pq vc cadastra e no final da ação limpa todos os seus campos! Quando for validar um campo a mensagem do erro vai aparecer e supostamente o form que o usuário preencheu desaparecerá! então   esses são os pepinos que estou tentando desenrolar

Comment: Nao teria uma logica para utilizar essa funcao só quando o usuario salvar os dados no banco??? se ele nao salvar nao limpa o form

Comment: Então, como você retorna os seus dados apos salvar com suceso, e apos dar erro?

Comment: dar uma olhadinha na controller, na action

Comment: tudo depende do que vem no retorno da sua `action` @HansMiller, dei uma editada no meu código de como costumo fazer em `PHP`, veja se consegue adaptar para `ASP`

Comment: Desculpa por nao responder ! Nao tive tempo valeu @Marcelo pela dica! apliquei a logica e deu certo

Comment: @HansMiller disponha :)